# using loop in JSX with react.js

Tags: reactjs

How to make this code use loop? I would like to have a working example but those I have tried does not work...

```
generateBoardRow(row) {
    return <div key={row} className="board-row">
        {this.renderSquare(row, 0)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 1)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 2)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 3)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 4)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 5)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 6)}
        {this.renderSquare(row, 7)}
    </div>
}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
generateBoardRow(row) {
    return <div key={row} className="board-row">
        for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        this.renderSquare(row, 0)
        this.renderSquare(row, 1)
        this.renderSquare(row, 2)
        this.renderSquare(row, 3)
        this.renderSquare(row, 4)
        this.renderSquare(row, 5)
        this.renderSquare(row, 6)
        this.renderSquare(row, 7)
        }
    </div>
}
```

but having compilation errors I can not understand.(near 'numrows;')

```
 Line 55:40:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

Comment: You can use `.map()` on your array basically. Can you please share what you have tried to render the expected loop? I suggest to read through the [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) section of **React** documentation. The *Rendering Multiple Components* part explains similar example what you need.

Comment: Please add the error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
generateBoardRow(row) {
    return (<div key={row} className="board-row">
         {Array.from(Array(8))
               .map((_,idx) => this.renderSquare(row, idx))}
          </div>);
}
```

Just make sure `idx` isn't being used as a key inside `renderSquare`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        this.renderSquare(row, 0)
        this.renderSquare(row, 1)
        this.renderSquare(row, 2)
        this.renderSquare(row, 3)
        this.renderSquare(row, 4)
        this.renderSquare(row, 5)
        this.renderSquare(row, 6)
        this.renderSquare(row, 7)
        }
```

means that for any `i` it gonna render square...

```
for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) this.renderSquare(row, i)
```

is render only the `i` square in any phase of the loop.

another thing is that it bit tricky to render `for` loop inside JSX `return`, so you might `map` instead

```
generateBoardRow(row) {
    return <div key={row} className="board-row">
    { Array(numrows).map((elem, i) => this.renderSquare(row, i)) }
      </div>
```